# How to ajax next & previous post on single page in Wordpress

Tags: ajax, wordpress

On my single.php template page I have nav links to the next and previous post. Currently when you click on the nav it takes you to the url page of the next or prev post. Instead I would like to load the next or prev post via Ajax into the current page, is this possible?

Comment: Yes this is possible. Enough?

Answer (score 2):

1. You need to target your nav links with custom selectors, let's say both links are in div #post_nav_links.
2. Using Javascript, you can easily the post using Ajax
   Here is a simple code ( i've used jQuery, Wordpress default class for post content is 'post' )

   ```
   $("#post_nav_links a").click(function(){
      var url = $(this).attr("href");
      $('.post').load(url + ' .post');
      return false;  
   })
   ```